# generics code - compilation error on jdk5, compiles fine on jdk6

Tags: java, generics, compilation

```
Map<Class<? extends Entity<?>>, EntityDAO<? extends Entity<?>>> dataAccessMap;
```

is used to store key -> value of entity class to DAO implementations that provide for CRUD of these entity classes.

```
public <T extends Entity<T>> EntityDAO<T> thatSupports(Class<T> entityClass) {
        if(dataAccessMap.containsKey(entityClass)) {
            return (EntityDAO<T>) dataAccessMap.get(entityClass);
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

this is a lookup API to get DAO implentation instance by entity class.

On JDK 1.5 (jdk1.5.0_22) the code does not compile.

```
Compilation failure inconvertible types
found   : EntityDAO<capture of ? extends Entity<?>>
required: EntityDAO<T>
```

However the code compiles and executes fine on JDK 6 (1.6.45)

Is there a way I can express this differently to compile on JDK 1.5. The method definitely has to return a EntityDAO

Comment: why you want to use old jdk. java 8 has been launched now

Comment: @javaBeginner, Java 8 is not released yet. It is still in Beta version. The schedule for the release is March 2014

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan i should have said beta

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. Please find below screenshots

[image: JDK 1.5]
[image: JDK 1.6]

Comment: which version of JDK are you using? Is it JDK 1.5.22

Comment: The version is  1.5.0_22-b03